# C++ system information displaying in a file

Tags: c++, file, system

I need to get a file information (its size and last update time) using system command `system ("dir")` , but it gives me many information that I don't want.

How can i get it to display only this info?

Comment: Please consider using [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for a portable solution.

Comment: How about using [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) and parse the output yourself? And do you really have to use the `dir` command externally do get that data? There are better functions, both in the WIN32 and POSIX-emulating layer for this, not to talk about using portable frameworks.

Comment: Explain "need". Do you have to turn in an assignment?

Comment: Well, parse the returned info and extract the parts you need..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `system ("dir /4 /T:W YOURFILE | findstr YOURFILE > temp.txt")` and you will get an output like:

```
C:\> dir /4 /T:W log.txt | findstr log.txt > t.txt
03/25/2014  10:39 AM           451,282 log.txt
```

in temp.txt, which you can parse as a normal file :P

/4 shows four characters for the year, /T:W returns last write time